# Override @CollectionTable reference to primary-key column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

### In short

JPA documentation says that [CollectionTable.joinColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html#joinColumns()) property is "The foreign key columns of the collection table which reference the primary table of the entity."

Can I make it reference not the primary key column of the entity table, but another column which has unique values?

### Details

There is a legacy database with following tables (simplified):

```
staff:
  user_id (int)
  user_name (varchar, primary key)

staff_privileges:
  id_user (int)
  privileges_id (int) 
  privileges_status (boolean)
```

Now I'm introducing Hibernate into the project and trying to map this tables to the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "staff")
public class User {

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private Integer userId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_name")
  private String userName;    // primary key column (legacy, cannot be changed)

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "staff_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "privileges_id")
  @Column(name = "privileges_status")
  private Map<Integer, Boolean> privileges; // privilegeId <-> isEnabled
}
```

Won't work because @CollectionTable creates reference to primary key: `staff_privileges.id_user -> staff.user_name (primary key)`.
It should be: `staff_privileges.id_user -> staff.id_user`.
Is there way to override this reference? Are there any Hibernate or JPA annotations for this? I would like to keep things simple and not introduce any new Entity or Embeddable if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `user_id` in also unique for each User then you could simply move the `@Id` annotation on `User` to `userId`: your JPA provider has no knowledge of what the actual PK is in the database so as long as that value is unique it would not cause any issues.

Slightly different context but see:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key

> **The JPA Id does not always have to match the database table primary
>   key constraint**, nor is a primary key or a unique constraint required.

The only difference would be if you were reverse engineering your tables from your mappings then the staff table would be created with PK on user_id rather than user_name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refrencedColumnName` to map `id_user` instead of `user_name` as a join column.

[Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.htm) has a more concise description about this parameter:

> The join column is declared with the @JoinColumn annotation which
> looks like the @Column annotation. It has one more parameters named
> **referencedColumnName**. **This parameter declares the column in the
> targeted entity that will be used to the join**. Note that when using
> **referencedColumnName** to a non primary key column, the associated class
> has to be Serializable. Also note that the referencedColumnName to a
> non primary key column has to be mapped to a property having a single
> column (other cases might not work).

So in your case (tested with [Hibernate 5.4.29.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.29.Final)):

(I implemented `Serializable` to avoid a related [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7668) to `referencedColumnName`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "staff")
public class User implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ...

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "staff_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "user_id"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "privileges_id")
  @Column(name = "privileges_status")
  private Map<Integer, Boolean> privileges;
}
```

For more check this SO question: [What is referencedColumnName used for in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244569/what-is-referencedcolumnname-used-for-in-jpa)

Comment: This answer is incorrect you can't use the source entity column in the referenceColumnName, you have reversed the sequence of name and referencedColumnName inside the join column, which will throw exception.

Comment: @theNoobProgrammer I don't think I reversed the columns inside `@JoinColumn`,
 from `referencedColumnName` documentattion : `...When used in a CollectionTable mapping, the referenced column is in the table of the entity containing the collection`. And I have just updated the answer to fix `ClassCastException`