# Hibernate CollectionTable - How to set the name of mapped table's column name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a **@CollectionTable** in a Spring RESTfull API. I have an Entity table named **University**. Now I am creating an Entity called **TargetedGift** where I will have a list of University's id which will be store in PostgreSQL database.

The **TargetedGift** Entity would like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "targeted_gifts")
public class TargetedGift { 
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "targeted_gift_id_generator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "targeted_gift_id_generator", 
         allocationSize 
        = 1)
        @Column(name="targeted_gift_id")
        private int targetedGiftID;
```

And the **University** Entity class would like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name ="universities")
public class DatabaseUniversity extends BasicEntity {

    @Column(name = "university_id")
    @Id
    private int universityId;

    @Column(name = "university_name")
    private String universityName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private DatabaseCity city;
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private int country_id;
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return universityId;
    }
```

}

I already have I separate table where I store a university details. In **TargetedGift** Entity I want to create a **CollectionTable** which will have **OneToMany** Relation between **CollectionTable** and **Universities** and this relation will be store in a separate table called **targeted_univeristy_ids**.

I could successfully create the relation table, set the table name as I want, also I could set the join column name (**TargeredGift** Entity's primary key). But I can't set the name for mapped Entity's (University's) primary key. Hibernate automatically producing a name which is `universityid_university_id`. I want this to be changed to only `university_id'.`

I searched in internet for this question and found few threads related to my question which're linked to `Stackoverflow` which help me to set the name for `joinColumn` of **TargetedGift** entity's. Till now columns in my  **targeted_univeristy_ids** look like this:

`table name: targeted_univeristy_ids
columns name:
-targeted_gift_id
- universityid_university_id`

[Here is one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209492/override-collectiontable-reference-to-primary-key-column) which has good explanation to rename the corresponding columns.

```
@ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "staff_privileges", joinColumns = 
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "privileges_id")
  @Column(name = "privileges_status")
  private Map<Integer, Boolean> privileges; // privilegeId <-> isEnabled
```

Following the above example, I understood that `@joinColumns` indicates the current Entity in which it locates, in my case, `TargetedGift` and
the the bottom `@olumn` indicate the foreign table's  primary key, which in my case is 'University's id (university_id). I followed this example and so far got the result as I mentioned above. Currently my code look this:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "targeted_univeristy_ids" , joinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(name = "targeted_gift_id", referencedColumnName = 
    "targeted_gift_id"))
   //@MapKeyColumn(name = "university_id")
    @Column(name = "university_id")
    private List<DatabaseUniversity> universityID;
```

Now I am looking for a solution to set the university's id column name from `universityid_university_id` to simply `university_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I was wrong creating it as  `@CollectionTable` where I have to create it as `@JoinTable`. Below is the code, which solved my problem:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="targeted_universities",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="targeted_gift_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="university_id")
    )
    private List<DatabaseUniversity> universities;
```