# Error SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000, using hibernate and javafx

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, javafx

I'm getting this error when trying to save data into a table that contains foreign key columns.

This is my scenario I'm picking two options from two different ComboBoxes (one option from each different ComboBox), I write two strings, all this to build my object to save but when committing I get this error:

> WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
>   ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`students`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `fk_student_career` FOREIGN KEY (`student_career`) REFERENCES `career` (`career_name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>   ERROR ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]

[These are my classes](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo) I placed them in my gists repositories to make this post a little bit short.

I have followed many tutorials and read a lot of info but can't manage to make it work. I have used the cascadetype, JoinColumn and many other things but failed in all...

Please help me...

P.S.: I'm self-learning and this a practice.

Comment: I think it's better to include the full [exception StackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Student` class mapping (I've included just the relevant part) to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student", catalog = "students")
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_career",referencedColumnName="career_name" nullable = false)
    private Career career;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_section", nullable = false)
    private Section section;

    ...
}
```

- [referencedColumnName](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName()) is used to explicitly map `Career` foreign key to the correct column `career_name` instead of its id `career_id`, check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244569/what-is-referencedcolumnname-used-for-in-jpa) for more detail.
- [CascadeType.PERSIST](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html#PERSIST) was added to save both to `Career` and `Section` while saving `Student`, if not, the database won't find the appropriate record for `Student`'s foreign keys, (and I think, this is the origin of the `SqlExceptionHelper`)

Comment: Wow! finally! Thank you, Sr. this solved my issue! thanks a lot, I really appreciate this help! thank you pretty much! I don't know if is the best method or the best way to do it! but it worked.

Comment: Glad it help! `I don't know if is the best method or the best way to do it!`, write a test scenario before the implementation, and if the test passes so your approach is correct.